# Programmatically setting number of processes with ray

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I want to use Ray to parallelize some computations in python. As part of this, I want a method which takes the desired number of worker processes as an argument.
The introductory articles on Ray that I can find say to specify the number of processes at the top level, which is different from what I want. Is it possible to specify similarly to how one would do when instantiating e.g. a multiprocessing Pool object, as illustrated below?

Example using multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return 2*x


def compute_results(x, n_jobs=4):
    with mp.Pool(n_jobs) as pool:
        res = pool.map(f, x)
    return res


data = [1,2,3]
results = compute_results(data, n_jobs=4)
```

Example using ray

```
import ray

# Tutorials say to designate the number of cores already here
ray.remote(4)
def f(x):
    return 2*x


def compute_results(x):
    result_ids = [f.remote(val) for val in x]
    res = ray.get(result_ids)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `f.remote()` four times then Ray will create four worker processes to run it.

Btw, you can use multiprocessing.Pool with Ray: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-more-libs/multiprocessing.html